# problem in understanding behaviour of initialization by inherited constructor

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I have this example: ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sb53P1b8M))

```
struct B1 {
    B1(int i): a(i) { std::cout << "B1" << std::endl; };
    int a;
};

struct B2 {
    int b;
    B2() { std::cout << "B2" << std::endl; }
};
                                                                                                                                                                                                             
struct D1 : B2, B1 {
    using B1::B1;
};

int main(void){
    D1 d = D1(1);

    std::cout << d.a << '\n'; //1
    std::cout << d.b; // underminate
}
```

Here, the initialization of D1 initializes B1 subobject by the inherited constructor and B2 subobject as there was a defaulted default constructor for B2. This behaviour is mandated by [[class.inhctor.init]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.inhctor.init#1) :

> When a constructor for type B is invoked to initialize an object of a different type D (that is, when the constructor was inherited ([namespace.udecl])), initialization proceeds as if a defaulted default constructor were used to initialize the D object and each base class subobject from which the constructor was inherited, except that the B subobject is initialized by the inherited constructor [..] **the initialization of the inherited constructor's parameters is sequenced before the initialization of any part of the D object**.

My problem is with the bold part: Why the standard mention "constructor's parameters" not "member-initializer-list"? I said so because after the parameter of constructor is initialized the member-initializer-list is executed. Is this mean that when a constructor parameter is initialized, member-initializer-list must be executed?

Comment: "as there were a defaulted default constructor for B1" is wrong (typo?) the whole thing happens as if there was a defaulted default constructor for `D`, which calls the other constructors

Comment: now I made the typo :D I meant `D1` not `D`

Answer (score 2):

The member initializer list is not the only place to prove an initializer. You can have in-class initializers too.

Consider for example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    foo(const foo&) {
        std::cout << "copy\n";
    }
    foo() {}
    foo(int) { std::cout << "init\n";}
};


struct B1 {
    B1(foo i): a(i) { std::cout << "B1" << std::endl; };
    foo a;
};

struct B2 {
    foo f = 42;
    B2() { std::cout << "B2" << std::endl; }
};
                                                                                                                                                                                                             
struct D1 : B2, B1 {
    using B1::B1;
};

int main(void){
    foo f;
    D1 d(f);
}
```

[output](https://godbolt.org/z/6vMbPch19):

```
copy
init
B2
copy
B1
```

The first `copy` is from `B1(foo i)` because that is sequenced before initialization of `foo f = 42;`, which causes `init` to be printed.

Similarly, if there was no initializer for the `B2::f` member at all, then its default constructor would be called (also before initialization of parameters of the `B1` constructor).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I somehow understood the rationale behind the bold part is the initialization of the constructor's parameter could potentially have a side effect. But the standard specifically talks about constructor parameters, why member-initializer-list is executed though? Is when ctor' parameters initialized, mem-init-list has to be executed?

Comment: I mean, this is like mem-init-list is part of initialization of constructor parameters.

Comment: @Mia there is also initialization via default values of constructor parameters and initialization via call of most-dervied class to a virtual base in "diamond" inheriatnce tree, where t goes "over head" of  interim derived classes, so you can't say it's a part. There is also impotant outcome that initialization of constructor parameters by default values cannot depend on non-static members or on `this`, static members will be initialized before.

Comment: @Mia oh well, not I see that I actually misread the question. The question is about " the initialization of the inherited constructor's parameters" not about "the initialization of any part of the D object.". Though, my example illustrates both. You can see that the parameter of the constructor `B1(foo i)` is initialized by copying the `foo f` from `main` before anything else happens.

Comment: @Mia i will try to think of a better example ...

Answer (score 0):

It's "*the inherited constructor*'s parameters". I.e. may be called in *member-initializer-list*, or it may be used as default:

```
struct A{
  int a;
  A(int v = 0) :a{v} {}
};

struct B : A {
  int b;
  B(int v) : A(v+1), b(a+1) {}
};

struct C : A {
  int c;
  C(int v) : c(a) {}
};
```

It might be somewhat obvious, but must have been defined. There are other ways to initialize class members, e.g. inline initialization AND a derived class can call a constructor of virtual base class directly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct V{
  int val;
  V(int v = 0, std::string field = "", std::string where = "") : val{v} { 
      std::cout << "V " 
                <<  (where.empty() ? "" : where + "::") 
                <<  (field.empty() ? "(unknown)" : field)
                <<  " = " << val 
                << std::endl; 
   }
};

struct A {
  V v1, v2;
  A() : v1{0, "v1", "A"}, v2{0, "v2", "A"}  {}
  A(int v) : v1{v, "v1", "A"}, v2{v + 1, "v2", "A"}  {}
};

struct B: virtual A {
  V v3;
  B(int v = 0) : A{v}, v3{v1.val + v, "v3", "B"} {};
};

struct C: virtual A {
  V v3;
  C(int v = 0) : A{v}, v3{v2.val + v, "v3", "C"} {};
};

struct D: B, C {
  V v4;
  // There is only one instance of A and we initilalize it here
  D(int v) : B{42}, C{63}, A{1}, v4{v2.val+v, "v4", "D"} {}
};

int main()
{
   D c {3};
}
```

Aforementioned rule would ensure that `A` will be initialized before parameters of `B::B(int)`, `C::C(int)` and `B`,`C` and `v4` initialization, even if order in member-initializer-list looks different (compiler may warn about reordering):

```
Output:    

 V A::v1 = 1
 V A::v2 = 2
 V B::v3 = 43
 V C::v3 = 65
 V D::v4 = 5
```

It may be important if initialization of members in interim classes `B` or `C` is depedant on values in class `A`. You can see that `B::v3` and `C::v3` are respecting latest values of `v1` and `v2`, which were initialized only once.